# Finding extrema of a continuous, univariate function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

**Problem:** Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x)=a(x-b)^2+c$, where $a,b,c$ are parameters. Find the minimum and maximum of $f$ depending on the values of $a,b,c$.

---

I understand how to do this, for the most part, as it's basic univariate calculus. What I'm not sure about is my solution, i.e. if it's sufficient.

I simply differentiated the function in question, and set it equal to $0$, giving me $2a(x-b) = 0$.

This means that $2a = 0$ and $(x-b) = 0$, implying that $a$ vanishes, and $x = b$.

So, I evaluated the function at the points $0, 1$, and $b$, giving me

$f(0) = a(0-b)^2 + c = ab^2 + c$

$f(1) = a(1-b)^2 + c = ab^2 - 2ab + c$

$f(b) = a(b-b)^2 + c = c$

But that's as far as I can get. How do I determine whether these are maxima or minima without numerical values for $a, b$, and $c$?

Comment: For $a\ne0$, the graph of $f$ is a parabola with vertex located at $(b,c)$. It "opens up" if $a>0$ and "open down" if $a<0$.

Comment: If $2a(x-b) =0$, then $2a=0$ **or** $x=b$, not **and**.

Comment: You cant "let $a$ vanish", $a$ is fixed and presumably non-zero. This means you have exactly one critical point ($x=b$). Note, as you did, $f(b)=c$. Looking at $f(0)=ab^2+c$, you can see $f(b)=c$ is  a minimum if $a>0$ and $b\ne0$; and $f(b)=c$ is a maximum if $a<0$ and $b\ne0$. If $b=0$, compare $f(0)=c$ with $f(1)=a+c$ (your evaluation of $f(1)$ is incorrect).

Comment: Ah, yes. I did mess up f(1). Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

A qualitative approach would be to use David's hints about the size and shape of the graph of $f(x)$, and proceed on a case-by-base basis.

- If $a=0$, the graph is a horizontal line.
- If $a>0$, the graph of $f$ over all real numbers is a parabola that has vertex at $(b,c)$ and opens upward.  Now compare $b$ to $0$ and $1$.  If $b < 0$, then $f(b) < f(0) < f(1)$.  Likewise if $b > 1$, then $f(0) > f(1) > f(b)$.  If $0 < b < 1$, you need to compare $f(0)  ab^2 + c$ with $f(1) = a(b-1)^2 + c$ and $f(b) = c$.
- If $a<0$, the graph of $f$ over all real numbers is a parabola that has vertex at $(b,c)$ and opens downward.  You can proceed similarly to the previous case.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!